# Python reading excel file perform time calculation and writing the result on the new column of the excel file

Tags: python-2.7, xlrd

I am new to Python I need help on reading datatype(time) data from Excel file perform time difference calculation and write the result on new column of the same excel file.

My code so far:

```
import xlrd
from datetime import time

book=xlrd.open_workbook("x1.xlsx")
print(book.nsheets)
print(book.sheet_names())
first_sheet=book.sheet_by_index(0)
print(first_sheet.row_values(0))
startrow=1
for row_index in range(startrow,first_sheet.nrows):
col1 = first_sheet.cell(row_index, 0)
col2 = first_sheet.cell(row_index, 1)
col3 = first_sheet.cell(2, 1)

x=(col1.value)
y=(col2.value)

if (x>y):
p=x-y
z=int(p*24*3600)
mytime= time(z//3600,(z%3600)//60,z%60)
print (mytime)
else:
print "00:00:00"
```

Comment: What happens with the code that you have written so far compared to what you want to see?

Comment: please help on writing the output to new column  in the excel file

Answer (score 1):

```
import xlwt
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('input.xls')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

data = [sheet.cell_value(0, col) for col in range(sheet.ncols)]

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet('test')

for index, value in enumerate(data):
    sheet.write(0, index, value)

workbook.save('output.xls')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if possible try and add some context around your code so the OP know what you have done and why, it'll make it more likely you'll get upvotes as well :) cheers!

Comment: my input excel file contains                                                                       On duty Clock In
8:30:00 8:14:00
13:30:00 13:53:00
8:30:00 8:02:00                                                                                   my previous code calculates the time difference but can't put the value on my 3rd column i want to put the calculated value on the same excel file of the 3rd column

Answer (score 1):

sadly you can't write into the exact same excel file. You can make yourself a copy of the existing file, manipulate it and save it as another file as this:

```
r_book = xlrd.open_workbook('x1.xls')
r_sheet = r_book.sheet_by_index(0)
w_book = copy(r_book)
ws = w_book.get_sheet(0)
```

then use ws.write(row,col,data) to fill out the info you want.
The output has to be a different file.